# How to change the order of jobs placing in the Machines - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I am newbie to javascript.I am doing a program sequencing number of jobs in n number of machine.I found this code logic online.But i have a small problem.That highest time consuming job goes to last machines.I want highest time consuming job should place on the first machine..
this is my ouput

```
8 Jobs Inserted
JobId:j8 Time to finish this Job :22
JobId:j7 Time to finish this Job :11
JobId:j3 Time to finish this Job :10
JobId:j2 Time to finish this Job :8
JobId:j4 Time to finish this Job :5
JobId:j5 Time to finish this Job :4
JobId:j1 Time to finish this Job :2
JobId:j6 Time to finish this Job :1
Machines Available :5
Output =====================================>
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
MachineId:M1 Jobs done by this Machine:(j4 = 5)(j5 = 9)(j6 = 10) Time consumed to finish all jobs:10
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
MachineId:M2 Jobs done by this Machine:(j2 = 8)(j1 = 10) Time consumed to finish all jobs:10
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
MachineId:M3 Jobs done by this Machine:(j3 = 10) Time consumed to finish all jobs:10
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
MachineId:M4 Jobs done by this Machine:(j7 = 11) Time consumed to finish all jobs:11
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
MachineId:M5 Jobs done by this Machine:(j8 = 22) Time consumed to finish all jobs:22
______________________________________________
Highest and Lowest Time consuming Machine =========>
M5 is the highest running Machine 22
M1 is the Lowest running Machine 10
M2 is the Lowest running Machine 10
M3 is the Lowest running Machine 10
```

code.js

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var njobs = [2,8,10,5,4,1,11,22];
var howManyMachines = 5;

console.log(njobs.length+" Jobs Inserted")

var jobswithvalue = Array(njobs.length).fill().map((m,i) => {
   //To remove Array Value 0
        var Jindex = i;
        if(Jindex == 0){
            Jindex = 1
        }else{
            Jindex = i + 1
        }

   return {
       jobname:"j"+Jindex,
       time:njobs[i]
   }
});



var sorted = jobswithvalue.sort((a,b) => b.time -a.time );


var machines = Array(howManyMachines).fill().map((m, i) => {
    var Mindex = i;
    if(i == 0){
       Mindex = 1
    }else{
        Mindex = i+1
    }
    return {
        id: i,
        value: 0,
        jobs: [],
        name:"M"+Mindex

    } });


sorted.map(function(data) {
    console.log('JobId:' + data.jobname + ' Time to finish this Job :' + data.time)
});



console.log('Machines Available :' + machines.length);
//Loop it and assign it
sorted.forEach(job => {
    var minMachine = machines
        .slice(1)
        .reduce((res, cur) =>
            res.value < cur.value ? res : cur, machines[0]);

    minMachine.jobs.push(job);
    minMachine.value += job.time;
});


//Prints the value

console.log('Output =====================================>');



machines.map(function(data) {
    var str = "MachineId:" + data.name + " Jobs done by this Machine:"
    data.jobs.reduce(function(total, curr) {
        var newTotal = total + curr.time;
        str += "(" + curr.jobname + " = " + newTotal + ")";
        return total + curr.time;
    }, 0);
    str += ' Time consumed to finish all jobs:' + data.value;
    console.log('___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________');
    console.log(str);
});



var high = Math.max.apply(Math, machines.map(function(o) {
    return o.value;
}));
console.log('______________________________________________')
console.log('Highest and Lowest Time consuming Machine =========>');

var resultHigh = _.filter(machines,function (item) {
    return item.value == high
});


resultHigh.map(function (data) {

    console.log(data.name+' is the highest running Machine '+data.value)
});

var low = Math.min.apply(Math, machines.map(function(o) {
    return o.value;
}));
var resultLow = _.filter(machines,function (item) {
    return item.value == low
});
resultLow.map(function (data) {

    console.log(data.name+' is the Lowest running Machine '+data.value)
});
```

this the code to modify

```
//Loop it and assign it
sorted.forEach(job => {
    var minMachine = machines
        .slice(1)
        .reduce((res, cur) =>
            res.value < cur.value ? res : cur, machines[0]);

    minMachine.jobs.push(job);
    minMachine.value += job.time;
});
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Did you see this line `var sorted = jobswithvalue.sort((a,b) => b.time -a.time );`? You should explain where you're having difficulty

Comment: No actually that is for sorting right

Comment: @JuanMendes I've updated the question i added where to modify

Comment: Do you want to evenly distribute the jobs to the available machines so that each machine has a balanced workload?